# .Net: DateTime String format

Tags: .net

I'm trying to add a timestamp to a file. However the `DateTime` Format `ToString()` looks weird to me.

Here is my code:

```
Dim _timeStamp As String = Date.Now.ToString("dd_mm_yyyy")
```

but the value looks like this:

> `_timeStamp = "03_24_2009"`

I checked my PC and the current date is correct. Shouldn't the value look like this: `03_03_2009`?

Comment: I did. I vote the first one up.

Comment: Didn't know about the check mark. i'll do so on all the question that i asked. thanks.

Comment: @Jack: No worries; it's just nice for posters (and other people with the same question) to know that a particular response answered/solved the OP's question/problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For 2-digit month number, use MM not mm. Captial M's refer to month, lowercase m's refer to minutes.

Also, John Sheehan has a [nice cheat-sheet](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/) for such things.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, "mm" means minutes and "MM" means months.

I find these MSDN pages useful:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

There are also various cheat sheets available on the web. I know I've seen a few of them around, but I only remember my own [DZone refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/coredotnet?oid=hom7545) which includes it ([also on Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7407143/Refcardz-18-Core-NET)).

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, [John Sheehan has one too](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/). Given that they're all free, why not download everything you can find and keep the one you find most useful? :)

Comment: Jon, I've put those pages into a cheat sheet: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/

Comment: @John: So have I, effectively - see the edit I was making when you commented :) I'll add your link too.

Answer (score 4):

Try using MM for month. The .ToString is case-sensitive, and lowercase means minutes.

Answer (score 2):

use MM, mm is for minutes

Answer (score 2):

mm is minutes. You want MM for months.

Answer (score 1):

I always get this right thanks to my mnemonic:

> Months are larger than minutes, "MM" is larger than "mm"