# DateTime Parse from String with specified format

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to extract datetime info from

```
"2012/04/03 10:06:21:611747"
```

using format

```
String dateformat = @"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff";
```

Getting an exception - any help is appreciated.

Full code

```
 String dateformat = @"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff";
 readonly CultureInfo _provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(line, dateformat, _provider);
```

Comment: Try capital MM for month. What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `MM` for months:

```
 String dateformat = @"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff";
```

Answer (score 5):

Your format should be:

`yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff`

You have a lower case `m` for month which is incorrect.

Have a look at this answer for more info: [.Net: DateTime String format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608057/net-datetime-string-format)

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
String dateformat = @"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff";
```

`MM` is for month, while `mm` is for minutes!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String dateformat = @"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ffffff";
```

Use MM for month.
The exception was ocurring due to confusion in interpreting m at two different places.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `mm` with `MM`

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) will help